# When to use and not use await with .map()

Tags: javascript

I'm confused with the use of await. Let's first assume that we want the code to complete in order.

Which of these are correct?

```
await items.map(async item => {
    return someFuncThatReturnsPromise();
});

items.map(async item => {
    return someFuncThatReturnsPromise();
});

await Promise.all(items.map(async item => {
    return someFuncThatReturnsPromise();
}));

Promise.all(items.map(async item => {
    return someFuncThatReturnsPromise();
}));
```

Is there more than one that is correct?

Comment: I have never seen `await` with `.map()` like that. I don't think `await` does anything on an array.

Comment: The `async` in all examples can be removed, I think. If the inner function already returns a promise, the `async` is redundant. Besides, in the current version only the 3rd example makes sense. all others would need some more code - with the first one never being useful (I imagine)

Comment: @Sirko yeah, mapping an array to an array of Promises to be used with `Promise.all()` makes perfect sense, but otherwise, it's weird.

Comment: 3rd differs from 4th as it awaits. Both can be "correct" but definitely are not equivalent. What kind of correctness you mean by correct?

Comment: @RoboRobok @Sirko Thanks, so remove `async` from all, and v1 and v2 don't do anything, but I thought the `await` in v3 was unnecessary.  I thought v4 was correct, right?

Comment: @WiktorZychla, correct in this case is wait for .map() to complete before continuing

Comment: As it stands, only the 3rd one waits for all async operations to finish before continuing.

Comment: @Sirko got it! Thanks. Post an answer so I can give your credit!

Comment: It's always cool to test these things with a delay function: `const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's at least two things to note here.

First, the `async` for all `map()` callbacks is not needed. If `someFuncThatReturnsPromise()` already returns a promise, `async` doesn't do anything and is redundant.

In the comments OP stated that the goal is to wait for all map-results to finish, before proceeding in the code. Under this condition only the third option is correct.
Let's examine what each option does (`async` already removed):

```
await items.map(item => {
    return someFuncThatReturnsPromise();
});
```

Here, the result of `items.map()` is an array (of Promises). When `await`ing anything that is not a `Promise` await doesn't do anything. So here, all async operations are started, but `await` will not wait for them to finish.

```
items.map(item => {
    return someFuncThatReturnsPromise();
});
```

Identical to the example above.

```
await Promise.all(items.map(item => {
    return someFuncThatReturnsPromise();
}));
```

That's the one you want to go for. [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) pretty much combines all `Promise`s of an array into a single `Promise` that resolves when all `Promise`s in the array resolve or rejects as soon as one of the inner `Promise`s rejects. Further, `await` gets a `Promise` to work with, so you're waiting until everything is done.

```
Promise.all(items.map(item => {
    return someFuncThatReturnsPromise();
}));
```

Same as above, but you never wait for the resulting `Promise` to finish. Hence, not your solution.

Comment: But using Promise.all doesn't guarantees order, so items[1] can resolve before items[0]. In addition I don't understand whats even the point to have  async item => ... if anyway someFuncThatReturnPromise already returns a promise and you are not using await within the function - so what's the point of that async.  everything looks wrong to me.

Comment: @Mercury The `async` is actually not needed as I wrote in the first paragraph and seemingly ignored afterwards -.-

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> await items.map(async item => {
>     return someFuncThatReturnsPromise();
> });
> ```

You're trying to `await` an array (that `items.map(…)` returned) here, that doesn't work as expected.

> ```
> items.map(async item => {
>     return someFuncThatReturnsPromise();
> });
> ```

You're not waiting for anything here. Statements after this `items.map(…)` call will run before all of the promises are fulfilled.

> ```
> Promise.all(items.map(async item => {
>     return someFuncThatReturnsPromise();
> }));
> ```

This is better, you're now creating a promise that fulfills when all of the promises from `someFuncThatReturnsPromise` are fulfilled. But you're still not waiting for that promise.

> ```
> await Promise.all(items.map(async item => {
>     return someFuncThatReturnsPromise();
> }));
> ```

This is the only properly working out of your snippets. Notice it can be simplified to

```
await Promise.all(items.map(item =>
    someFuncThatReturnsPromise()
));
```

or even

```
await Promise.all(items.map(someFuncThatReturnsPromise));
```

> Let's first assume that we want the code to complete in order.

If you refer other statements in your program, yes they would run after this `await` statement.

But if you're referring to the `someFuncThatReturnsPromise` calls, no, these are executing concurrently, as `items.map(…)` kicks them off all at once. If you wanted to run them sequentially, you would need to use

```
for (const item of items) {
    await someFuncThatReturnsPromise()
}
```